expanding a function in terms of radical powers

Is it possible to expand the function $f(x)=x^2$ in terms of the
radical powers of the form $x^s$ where $0<s<1$? In other words, is
there a way to write $$x^2=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^{si}$$ for some real
coefficients $a_i$ to be determined and $0<s<1$?

I know it may have something to do with a modification of the Maclaurin expansion at $x=0$. But I am not able to get any result along that line. Any help is appeciated.

I'll assume we're looking at $x > 0$, so we don't have to worry about $x^s$ as a multivalued function for complex $x$.
If $t = x^s$, then $x^2 = t^{2/s}$ and you want to write
$$ t^{2/s} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i t^i $$
The right side is an ordinary Maclaurin series; if it converges anywhere besides $t=0$, it converges to an analytic function of $t$ in a neighbourhood of $t = 0$.  However, the left side is not analytic at $t=0$ unless $2/s$ is a positive integer; that corresponds to
the "trivial" case $a_{2/s} = 1$, $a_i = 0$ otherwise.
